# Nesting methods in ES6 classes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have been trying to follow a DRY programming and I have been repeating myself so I tried to nest methods within a parent method that help some code.

```
chat() {
  client.on("chat", (channel, user, message, self) => {

   method() {
     // code here
   }

   method() {
     // code here
   {

  }
}
```

But that didn't work out as expected
calling `class.chat.method()` didn't bring back anything. What I really need help with is removing my DRY programming I call `client.on("chat", callback())` every single method I use. Curious whether this can be prevented and have just one snippet with methods called within it.

FULL CODE:

```
watchFor(command, res, sendersName, prefix) {
    this.client.on("chat", (channel, user, message, self) => {
        console.log(this._showSendersName.whitelistedCommands);
        if (message == this.prefix + command || message == prefix + command) {
            return this.client.say(channel, res);
        }
    });
}
modOnly(command, res) {
    this.client.on("chat", (channel, user, message, self) => {
        if (this._showSendersName == false) {
            if (self) return
        }
        if (message == this.modPrefix + command && user.mod || message == this.prefix + command && user.mod) {
            return this.client.say(channel, res);
        } 
    });
} 
broadcasterOnly(command, res) {
    this.client.on("chat", (channel, user, message, self) => {
            if (this._showSendersName == false) {
                if (self) return
            }
            if (message == this.prefix + command && user.badges.broadcaster == 1) {
                return this.client.say(channel, res);
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to put them on an altogether different object, not the `client` that deals with the events?

Comment: Umm, what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I want chat to deal with the events but I want just one chat event instead of calling chat event every single time I write a new method in the class.

Comment: That you cannot nest methods. You'll want to use two objects, a `client` and a `chat`. If you show us your full, real code, we might be able to suggest something specific.

Comment: Alright, posted my code

Comment: How are you calling those methods? I suppose that's the part that should be inside the event listener.

Comment: On the app.js I would've called it like ```bot.chat().watchFor();```

Comment: Without any arguments? Only one single call to that method?

Comment: .watchFor(command, res) that's the params for watchfor

Answer (score 1):

You can't use ES6 method definition shorthand outside of object initializers.  Try declaring another function once inside function scope:

```
chat() {
  client.on("chat", (channel, user, message, self) => {

    const sharedMethod = () => {
      // code here
    }

    sharedMethod()
  })
}
```

Comment: Now, that is technically what I am looking for however, would I still be repeating myself with that? On the app.js I would need to call bot.chat().sharedMethod() is that possible?